# How to test dataclass that can be initialized with environment variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables, pytest, python-dataclasses

I have the following dataclass:

```
import os
import dataclasses

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Example:
    host: str = os.environ.get('SERVICE_HOST', 'localhost')
    port: str = os.environ.get('SERVICE_PORT', 30650)
```

How do I write a test for this? I tried the following which looks like it should work:

```
from stackoverflow import Example
import os


def test_example(monkeypatch):
    # GIVEN environment variables are set for host and port
    monkeypatch.setenv('SERVICE_HOST', 'server.example.com')
    monkeypatch.setenv('SERVICE_PORT', '12345')
    #   AND a class instance is initialized without specifying a host or port
    example = Example()
    # THEN the instance should reflect the host and port specified in the environment variables
    assert example.host == 'server.example.com'
    assert example.port == '12345'
```

but this fails with:

```
====================================================================== test session starts ======================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.12, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/biogeek/tmp
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                

test_example.py F                                                                                                                                         [100%]

=========================================================================== FAILURES ============================================================================
_________________________________________________________________________ test_example __________________________________________________________________________

monkeypatch = <_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch object at 0x7f39de559220>

    def test_example(monkeypatch):
        # GIVEN environment variables are set for host and port
        monkeypatch.setenv('SERVICE_HOST', 'server.example.com')
        monkeypatch.setenv('SERVICE_PORT', '12345')
        #   AND a class instance is initialized without specifying a host or port
        example = Example()
        # THEN the instance should reflect the host and port specified in the environment variables
>       assert example.host == 'server.example.com'
E       AssertionError: assert 'localhost' == 'server.example.com'
E         - server.example.com
E         + localhost

test_example.py:12: AssertionError
==================================================================== short test summary info ====================================================================
FAILED test_example.py::test_example - AssertionError: assert 'localhost' == 'server.example.com'
======================================================================= 1 failed in 0.05s =======================================================================
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your tests fail because your code loads the environment variables **when you import the module**. Module-level code is **very hard to test**, as the `os.environ.get()` calls to set the default values have already run before your test runs.  You'd have to effectively *delete* your module from the `sys.modules` module cache, and only import your module after mocking out the `os.environ` environment variables to test what happens at import time.

You could instead use a [`dataclass.field()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field) with a `default_factory` argument; that executes a callable to obtain the default whenever you create an instance of your dataclass:

```
import os
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from functools import partial


@dataclass
class Example:
    host: str = field(default_factory=partial(os.environ.get, 'SERVICE_HOST', 'localhost'))
    port: str = field(default_factory=partial(os.environ.get, 'SERVICE_PORT', '30650'))
```

I used the [`functools.partial()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to create a callable that'll call `os.environ.get()` with the given name and default.

Note that I also changed the default value for `SERVICE_PORT` to a string; after all, the `port` field is annotated as a `str`, not an `int`. :-)

If you *must* set these defaults from environment variables at import time, then you could have `pytest` mock out these environment variables in a [`conftest.py` module](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#conftest-py-sharing-fixtures-across-multiple-files); these are imported before your tests are imported, so you get a chance to tweak things before your module-under-test is imported. This won't let you run multiple tests with different defaults, however:

```
# add to conftest.py at the same package level, or higher.

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="session")
def mock_environment(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setenv('SERVICE_HOST', 'server.example.com')
    monkeypatch.setenv('SERVICE_PORT', '12345')
```

The above fixture example, when placed in `conftest.py`, would automatically patch your environment before your tests are loaded, and so before your module is imported, and this patch is automatically undone at the end of the test session.